# controller vs channel in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am starting to create a web-app in [phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/). I had looked at few of the tutorials as well as creating chat example from [chrismccord](http://www.chrismccord.com/blog/2014/05/06/how-to-build-an-elixir-chat-app-with-phoenix/). When we generate `ecto` models, they generate CRUD web pages using controller, which works for a simple purpose and not for realtime updates. I am little bit confused when to use controllers and when to use channels, is it only when real-time updates are required?

Also is there a way to use both together for a particular form/webpage, where certain tasks are done on controllers and certain in channel. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Channels are for real-time communication. Controllers are for normal HTTP request-response communication.

Controllers are often based on database resources, so the usual CRUD operations are generated for you. But the use cases for real-time are more varied. I don't think there is anything that could be considered a default implementation to produce by the generator.

You can definitely use both channels for real-time updates and regular controllers within one page, but you need to write the code for channels yourself.